# Is half of Rocket Lab still owned by Mark Rocket?

Tags: history, rocketlab, business

Wikipedia's [Rocket Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab) links to Spaceflight Insider's [Rocket Lab: The Electron, the Rutherford, and why Peter Beck Started it in the First Place](https://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/commercial/rocket-lab-electron-rutherford-peter-beck-started-first-place/) which links to The Otago Daily Time's 2009 arrticle [Fisher and Paykel fuelled flames in novice rocket-maker](https://www.odt.co.nz/news/dunedin/fisher-and-paykel-fuelled-flames-novice-rocket-maker) which says:

> He went on to work on the design of superyachts and spent five years working for Crown-owned Industrial Research Ltd, before setting up his own company.
>
> "I reached a point where it was time to do something, so I formed Rocket Labs, quit the day job and managed to secure investment to be able to start the [space] programme."
>
> He sold half to investor **Mark Rocket.**
>
> He agreed it would be fair to describe him as "the brains" **and Mr Rocket "the money" behind the venture.**

And shows a photo of (apparently) the two with the caption:

> Rocket Labs technical director Peter Beck (left) and **business development director Mark Rocket** at the unveiling of a mock-up of the Atea 1 suborbital space rocket in August. Photo by NZPA.

**Question:** Is half of Rocket Lab still owned by Mark Rocket? Or was there some subsequent dilution as Rocket Lab grew and became a wholly owned New Zealand subsidiary of Rocket Lab the public American aerospace manufacturer? Assuming the answer is "No", are both of their ownerships *still roughly comparable?*

Comment: Most if not all of the information necessary to answer should be in the public domain as Rocket Lab is now a publicly traded company. [Rocket Lab is a public American aerospace manufacturer and small satellite launch service provider with a wholly owned New Zealand subsidiary.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab)

Comment: Someone named "Mark Rocket" invests in a rocketry startup, and this is the question you ask?

Comment: @RussellBorogove "Is Mark Rocket's name actually Mark Rocket?" probably wouldn't have flown, so I tried an indirect approach.